# Javascript Array.prototype.reduce

Tags: javascript, массивы

**Внимание: это не вопрос о том, как решить задачу симметричной разности. Это вопрос про Array.prototype.reduce и как она работает.**

Выполнял задания на freecodecamp, столкнулся с заданием по симметричной разности, сделал через массивы, обычным способом, прошло проверки, всё хорошо. В полезных ссылках были ссылки на ресурсы:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PxffSUQRkG4

По заданию предполагалось, что я буду использовать метод reduce для решения. Однако, хоть и решив по другому, я не могу понять как работает сама функция reduce.

Просьба объяснить или дать ссылку на объяснение и разжевывание (так сказать на пальцах показать), чтобы понять как эта функция решила задачу симметричной разности.

Я понимаю, что она перебирает массив, и обрабатывает его, однако не могу понять как функция, которая передаётся как callback-параметр в reduce, поняла какие массивы ей сравнивать, как они ей так передались по очереди, попарно... Хочу разобраться с ней, чтобы это не было каким-то неизвестным пропущенным местом в этом нелёгком изучении javascript. Спасибо!

```
function sym() {
  var args = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        args.push(arguments[i]);
    }

    function symDiff(arrayOne, arrayTwo) {
        var result = [];

        arrayOne.forEach(function(item) {
            if (arrayTwo.indexOf(item) < 0 && result.indexOf(item) < 0) {
                result.push(item);
            }
        });

        arrayTwo.forEach(function(item) {
            if (arrayOne.indexOf(item) < 0 && result.indexOf(item) < 0) {
                result.push(item);
            }
        });

        return result;
    }

    return args.reduce(symDiff);
}

sym([1, 1, 2, 5], [2, 2, 3, 5], [3, 4, 5, 5]);
```

Comment: возможно я не совсем понял вопрос: код который приведен - это твое решение? или нет? В нем уже используется reduce

Comment: код это решение, правильное решение с использованием reduce, то как это поидее требовалось решить на freecodecamp (код не мой, но рабочий). а я хотел бы понять это решение на основе reduce

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Эту операцию ещё называют "свёрткой". Она начинает с какого-то начального значения (если оно явно не указано, то обычно с первого элемента) и последовательно "заворачивает" в него элемент за элементом, пока коллекция (массив) не кончится.

В вашем примере она обобщает симметрическую разность **двух** множеств (`symDiff`) на **N** множеств (`sym`).

Проще всего объяснить механизм работы `reduce` для вашего случая будет так:

```
sym(a, b, c)    == [a, b, c].reduce(symDiff)    == symDiff(symDiff(a, b), c)

sym(a, b, c, d) == [a, b, c, d].reduce(symDiff) == symDiff(symDiff(symDiff(a, b), c), d)
```

---

Забавно, что `sym`, в отличие от `symDiff`, может принимать и один аргумент. Его же в этом случае и вернёт. Если вы рассматриваете симметрическую разность **одного** элемента.

---

Можно пойти ещё дальше и определить симметрическую разность **нуля** элементов. Нынешняя функция упадёт, попытавшись её вычислить.

Распространённая практика для таких случаев это возвращать **нейтральный элемент** для переданной функции. [Для симметрической разности это пустое множество](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C#.D0.A1.D0.B2.D0.BE.D0.B9.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B2.D0.B0). Достаточно просто передать его как начальное значение для `reduce`:

```
return args.reduce(symDiff, []);
```

...и `reduce` начнёт "заворачивать" элементы не в первый элемент, а в него. А для пустой коллекции будет возвращён он же в неизменном виде.

Минус, хоть и небольшой, в том, что для двух аргументов ваша версия вызовет `symDiff` единожды, а с упомянутым изменением — дважды.

Comment: @VladimirMedinsky, нет не правильно. у коллбэка reduce следующие параметры: `acc` - аккумулятор, в котором результат предыдущего шага,`current` - текущий элемент коллекции, `index` - индекс текущего элемента, `array` - коллекция, по которой происходит перебор. И именно в таком порядке.